# Using .groupby and .resample to carry out operations on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a time series in a `Pandas` `DataFrame`, one of my columns contains daily residuals from model predictions. I'd like to find the monthly average and subtract this monthly average from each of the daily model predictions. Is there a some combination of `.groupby` and `.resample` that I could use to code this?

```
monthly_res = sve_DOC['sRes'].resample('M', how='mean')
sve_DOC['RIMsDOC2'] = sve_DOC['RIMsDOC'] - monthly_res
```

I can get the monthly average, but I don't know how to ensure that the correct monthly average is used on each daily model prediction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [transform](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation):

```
g = sve_DOC['sRes'].groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M'))
g.transform('mean')

sve_DOC['RIMsDOC2'] = sve_DOC['RIMsDOC'] - g.transform('mean')
```

*Note: you have to use TimeGrouper to groupby months (just like you would in the resample).*

Comment: I have a follow up question. Is it possible to `.groupby`, `pd.TimeGrouper` or `.resample` by 'absolute' month, meaning if a dataset spans multiple years, it will be reduce to just 12 rows (one for each month). Or is the only way to write a function to check the month field?

Comment: @Bprodz I think I would just do `.groupby(df.index.month)`

Comment: I'm not sure why but it doesn't seem to work whether I pass a series or df. `print test.groupby(test.index.month).head()` doesn't affect the data, although no errors occur and `print test.index.month` returns a list of month numbers. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I don't think `head` does what you think it does: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#taking-the-first-rows-of-each-group/ (try doing some kind of aggregation). Note: this should probably be another question!

Comment: Gosh, you're right- thanks for link. I've started another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212659/how-to-preview-rows-after-using-groupby-on-a-pandas-df-series) if you have any further comment?