# How to preview rows after using .groupby() on a Pandas df/series

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

After using `df.groupby(df.index.month)` I would like to preview my `DataFrame` unfortunately `.head` removes the group formatting and `df['col'][:3]` returns the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-6783abceafb8> in <module>()
      1 test= sve_DOC
      2 test = test.groupby(test.index.month)
----> 3 print test['DOC_mg/L'][:3]

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    487 
    488     def __getitem__(self, key):
--> 489         raise NotImplementedError
    490 
    491     def _make_wrapper(self, name):

NotImplementedError:
```

Is there any way around this?

Update: After checking the groups I wanted to do some which operations on the data which I did based on @chrisb's post `test.get_group(5)['col'].median()`

Comment: Do you want to preview part of each group?  Or just the first N (3) groups?

Comment: @chrisb To be honest I wasn't sure how `.groupby()` worked so I just wanted to have a look. Using @user2600939's method I see that I essentially have 12 dataframes. Do you know how I can index them? `print test[1]` works when used in a loop but not when used by itself.

Comment: It's not clear what you're wanting to preview...

Comment: @AndyHayden I'd wanted to see the first few rows and column headings like using `.head()` on a `DataFrame`, to check that the `groupby` object was organised correctly. `.get_group()` and `.group.keys()` turned out to be what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?  `gb` is the GroupBy object.  This prints the first 5 rows from the first 3 groups.

```
In [230]: gb = df.groupby(df.index.month)

In [231]: for k in gb.groups.keys()[:3]:
     ...:     print gb.get_group(k)[:5]
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was after. I didn't realise that the data was moved around as it is, otherwise I my question would have been how to access the different groups, and data within those groups.

After checking the groups I wanted to do some which operations on the data which I did based on your post `test.get_group(5)['col'].median()`

Answer (score 1):

you can loop through test

```
test = df.groupby("columnTitle")
for each in test:
    print each[0] #columnTitle value
    print each[1] #corresponding df equivalent of df[df['columnTitle']==each[0]]
```