# look at only one group in group by pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to view one or a few groups at a time in pandas groupby?

I tried the following:

```
df.groupby('DOCNUMBER').head()
```

But it returns indexer objects.

Comment: Doesn't `df.groupby('DOCNUMBER').head(1)` or `df.groupby('DOCNUMBER').first()` do what you want?

Comment: Try this answer for iterating over the first few groups - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212659/how-to-preview-rows-after-using-groupby-on-a-pandas-df-series/24212855#24212855